# Распечатать документ (таблицу) C# в .docx, данные идут из базы данных, разбив одну ячейку на столбцы

Tags: c#, wpf

Я написал код распечатать таблицу

```
    private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var word = new Word.Application();
        try
        {
            var document = word.Documents.Add();
            var paragrah = word.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add();
            var tableRange = paragrah.Range;
            var inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList = AppData.db.InventoryObjectInentoryObjectDetails.ToList();
            var table = document.Tables.Add(tableRange, inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList.Count, 16);
            table.Borders.Enable = 1;
            table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Наименование";
            table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Инвентарный номер";
            table.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Дата ввода в эксплуатацию";
            table.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Срок службы";
            table.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Возможность списания";
            table.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "Тип";
            table.Cell(1, 7).Range.Text = "Подтип";
            table.Cell(1, 8).Range.Text = "Наименование)";
            table.Cell(1, 9).Range.Text = "Серийный номер";
            table.Cell(1, 10).Range.Text = "Документация";
            table.Cell(1, 11).Range.Text = "Состояние";
            table.Cell(1, 12).Range.Text = "Номер акта";
            table.Cell(1, 13).Range.Text = "Дата акта";
            table.Cell(1, 14).Range.Text = "Ответственный";
            table.Cell(1, 15).Range.Text = "Цена";

            int i = 2;
            foreach (var item in inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList)
            {
                table.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.InventoryNumber;
                table.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CommissioningDate.ToLongTimeString();
                table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.LifeTime.ToString();
                table.Cell(i, 5).Range.Text = "ДА";
                table.Cell(i, 6).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Type.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 7).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.SubType.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 8).Range.Text = item.InventoryObjectDetails.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 9).Range.Text = item.InventoryObjectDetails.SeriaNumber;
                table.Cell(i, 10).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.DocumentationPath;
                table.Cell(i, 11).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.Status.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 12).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.NumberAct;
                table.Cell(i, 13).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.Date.ToString();
                table.Cell(i, 14).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Employe.FIO;
                table.Cell(i, 15).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Amount.ToString();
                i++;
            }
            document.SaveAs2($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Ведомость инвентаризации.docx");
            document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            word.Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            MessageBox.Show("Сохранение прошло успешно!", "Сохранено!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source + " выдал исключение!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            word.Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        }
    }
```

Данный код печатает то что нужно, но вот проблема, результат этого кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А добиться нужно такого результата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Исходный код программы GitHub](https://github.com/vckit/thevckit-repos/tree/master/Inventory%20Kwok/InventoryApp)

Кто может показать, как мне один столбец под названием Комплектующие раздробить на несколько ячеек и указать данные из отдельной таблицы Комплектующие?

Comment: Ячейки не разбиваются, вместо этого формируется несколько столбцов, а ячейки объединяются, то есть в обратную сторону все происходит.

Comment: @aepot, могли бы показать пример? Я просто не совсем понимаю

Comment: Откройте ворд и попробуйте руками такую таблицу сделать, попутно пишите код, повторяя ваши же ручные операции. Именно так оно и делается. Либо создайте всю таблицу руками, сохраните в файл, а в коде его откройте, а таблицу заполняйте и добавляйте строки. Никто вас не заставляет формировать документ програмно с нуля.

Comment: @aepot, я честно сказать, на практике вообще не понял, как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: Я бы на практике вообще этой мутью не занимался, гораздо проще сгенерить HTML файл, а потом хоть в ворд, хоть в PDF его засунуть.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var word = new Word.Application();
        try
        {
            var document = word.Documents.Add();
            var paragrah = word.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add();
            var tableRange = paragrah.Range;
            var inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList = AppData.db.InventoryObjectInentoryObjectDetails.ToList();
            var table = document.Tables.Add(tableRange, inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList.Count, 16);
            table.Range.Font.Size = 10;
            table.Borders.Enable = 1;
            table.Title = "Ведомость инвентаризации";
            table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Наименование";
            table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Инвентарный номер";
            table.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Дата ввода в эксплуатацию";
            table.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Срок службы";
            table.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Возможность списания";
            table.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "Тип";
            table.Cell(1, 7).Range.Text = "Подтип";
            table.Cell(1, 8).Range.Text = "Комплектующие";
            table.Cell(1, 9).Range.Text = "";
            table.Cell(1, 10).Range.Text = "";
            table.Cell(1, 11).Range.Text = "Документация";
            table.Cell(1, 12).Range.Text = "Состояние";
            table.Cell(1, 13).Range.Text = "Номер акта";
            table.Cell(1, 14).Range.Text = "Дата акта";
            table.Cell(1, 15).Range.Text = "Ответственный";
            table.Cell(1, 16).Range.Text = "Цена";

            int i = 2;
            foreach (var item in inventoryObjectInventoryObjectDetailsList)
            {
                table.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.InventoryNumber;
                table.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CommissioningDate.ToLongTimeString();
                table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.LifeTime.ToString();
                table.Cell(i, 5).Range.Text = "ДА";
                table.Cell(i, 6).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Type.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 7).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.SubType.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 8).Range.Text = item.InventoryObjectDetails.ID.ToString();
                table.Cell(i, 9).Range.Text = item.InventoryObjectDetails.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 10).Range.Text = item.InventoryObjectDetails.SeriaNumber;
                table.Rows[1].Cells[8].Merge(table.Rows[1].Cells[9]);
                table.Cell(i, 11).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.DocumentationPath;
                table.Cell(i, 12).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.Status.Title;
                table.Cell(i, 13).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.NumberAct;
                table.Cell(i, 14).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.CurrentStatus.Date.ToString();
                table.Cell(i, 15).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Employe.FIO;
                table.Cell(i, 16).Range.Text = item.InventoryObject.Amount.ToString();
                i++;
            }
            document.SaveAs2($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Ведомость инвентаризации.docx");
            document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            word.Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            MessageBox.Show($"Ведомость успешно сформирована, расположение: {Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Ведомость инвентаризации.docx!", "Ведомость успешно сформирован.", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source + "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            word.Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        }
```